# Running difference month over month

Tags: sql, date, select, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a sample data, i want to get the Difference in month over month data 'Lag' column for only row B

[image]

Comment: How do you define "B"?  That column has no name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there always is just one row per month and `id`, then just use `lag()`. You can wrap this in a `case` expression so it only applies to `id` `'B'`.

```
select 
    id,
    date,
    data,
    case when id = 'B' 
        then data - lag(data) over(partition by id order by date) 
    end lag_diff
from mytable
```